# Sybase Upgrade 12.5 to 15.7 with a CIS link between two dataservers

Tags: upgrade, sybase

I am planning to upgrade a sybase dataserver from 12.5 to 15  which shares a CIS link with another 12.5 sybase dataserver.These dataservers share some tables and hence a lot of joins are across dataservers including some #temp tables.These joins are taking a lot of time to execute when there is a procedure call from say dataserver A(12.5) to dataserver B(15) where A and B have a CIS(Component Integration Services) link.
what can be done to optimize these joins??

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

In ASE 15, enable 'join relocation' and see if that affects the performance.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Rob
this is done using sp_serveroption , correct? is this command not available in 12.5 ase?i mean the relocation join ?

Comment: This is available only in ASE 15.0.2 or later. Indeed it is configured with sp_serveroption. In addition you also need to set "sp_dboption tempdb, 'ddl in tran', true" in the remote server.